# How go through the entire json array - POSTGRESQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I have such a structure like that:

```
[{"uniqid": "LL.NEW", "time": 1}, {"uniqid": "LL.MODIFY", "time": 3}]
```

how can i walk over this structure to get something like this?

[image: Structure]

I tried used json_each function but i have array.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [JSON Processing Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

For your task you can use `json_to_recordset` like this:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  json_to_recordset(
    '[{"uniqid": "LL.NEW", "time": 1}, {"uniqid": "LL.MODIFY", "time": 3}]'::json
  ) as x(uniqid text, time integer);
```